# What's the best way to create a csv file from SQL?

Tags: csv, ssis, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2015

I have a SQL table with weekly payroll information in it.  I currently run a Stored Procedure picking the 2 weeks (@WeekEnding1, @Weekending2) that I want to include.  This is then manually converted into a csv file for import into the payroll software.

I have tried using SSIS to create the file.

I have 2 issues;

1. - The date needs to be formatted as YYMMDD and this has to be numeric as stipulated by the import.
2. - Can I pass the variables used in the Stored procedure?

Or is there another solution in SQL?

Thanks in advance

Gerry

Comment: This can be done through SSIS.  Your 2 issues should not be show stoppers for SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

Change your stored procedure to transform the date & time to the format that you want. You can do this with the CONVERT function.

```
    SELECT CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), YourDateColumn, 12) AS NUMERIC) from Your_Table
```

From there use the Import/Export wizard, select the 'write a query...' option and then either use your stored procedure or use the query from your stored procedure.

Lastly, use the Import/Export wizard to export to CSV as desired.

The Cast and Convert info is here: [MSDN Cast & Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), you want #12, ISO format.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using BCP (Bulk Copy Program)?

It is fairly straight forward to use and there are a lot of options available with it.

I'd google for more info but in the meantime, check out this very good article:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/

Will add an example later but out and about at the moment.